# Key-Value on top of Appengine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, datanucleus

Although appengine already is schema-less, there still need to define the entities that needed to be stored into the `Datastore` through the `Datanucleus` persistence layer. So I am thinking of a way to get around this; by having a layer that will store Key-value at runtime, instead of compile-time Entities.

The way this is done with Redis is by creating a key like this:

```
private static final String USER_ID_FORMAT = "user:id:%s";
private static final String USER_NAME_FORMAT = "user:name:%s";
```

From the docs Redis types are: `String`, `Linked-list`, `Set`, `Sorted set`. I am not sure if there's more.

As for the GAE datastore is concerned a String "Key" and a "Value" have to be the entity that will be stored.

Like:

```
public class KeyValue {
 private String key;
 private Value value; // value can be a String, Linked-list, Set or Sorted set etc.
 // Code omitted
}
```

The justification of this scheme is rooted to the Restful access to the datastore (that is provided by Datanucleus-api-rest)

Using this rest api, to persist a object or entity:

```
POST http://datanucleus.appspot.com/dn/guestbook.Greeting
{"author":null,
  "class":"guestbook.Greeting",
  "content":"test insert",
  "date":1239213923232}
```

The problem with this approach is that in order to persist a Entity the actual class needs to be defined at compile time; unlike with the idea of having a key-value store mechanism we can simplify the method call:

```
POST http://datanucleus.appspot.com/dn/org.myframework.KeyValue
{ "class":"org.myframework.KeyValue"
  "key":"user:id:johnsmith;followers",
  "value":"the_list",
}
```

Passing a single string as "value" is fairly easy, I can use JSON array for list, set or sorted list. The real question would be how to actually persist different types of data passed into the interface. Should there be multiple KeyValue entities each representing the basic types it support: KeyValueString? KeyValueList? etc.

Comment: What is the problem you are trying to solve?  (I get the "no compile time definitions", but q is why not?  What is your use-case?)

Comment: @alphazero Yes, good point. However, I want to leverage on GAE while having the flexibility of persisting "any kind of data" which I believe is very well suited for a Restful web service. I mean, I can key-in values and retrieve them at any point in time.

Comment: @alphazero By just doing POST I can store a Key-value and by going a GET method I can query a value like: GET http ://localhost/dn/org.myframework.KeyValue?key=='user:id:johnsmith' and this would return the json object for example.

Comment: Somehow I think this would make persisting data more flexible and less painful. I'm thinking of this project more of a open-source project that I need to start really soon,

Comment: @alphazero As per your question, I believe the use-case would be for web services. For web services to have a way to easily persist data without really doing the hoops in defining the back-end persistence layer upfront.

Comment: Will some random program pass a random 'object' to your program?  That would be a rare program.  Unless you are just holding on to random bytes and then passing them back out, some degree of transparency/semantics is required for meaningful work. Even when using a K/V e.g. Redis you are in fact establishing those semantics in your code.  2 words of advice: (1) "Pain" in context of data typically indicates lack of knowledge regarding what purpose the "pain" serves. (2) Don't complicate your life -- you already have a persistent layer ...

Comment: @alphazero Well as for me, I'm not reinventing the persistence layer. I'm just adding a way to have things stored "on-the-fly". I think this is more of a "protocol" type of thing, in a way that we store in KeyValue and we define our own key-ing pattern as per our requirements.

Comment: @alphazero Also I'm just leveraging on existing software, like the Datanucleus Rest API, and that when you query the datastore you're actually talking to the Datanucleus supplied rest api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're using a JSON based REST API, so why not just store Value as a JSON string?

Comment: Good point. I was thinking to mimic the Redis types, however JSON string might do the job, after all its the application using the datastore to know the data types paired with the keys...

Comment: I think the best idea is to ditch Java, use Python, and use the Expando datastore type.  But if you must use java, it'll be a lot of low level API work to manipulate the data types per entity.  It'll be much simpler using a JSON string

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to use the Datanucleus layer, or any of the other fine ORM layers (like Twig or Objectify).  Those are optional, and are all based on the low-level API.  If I interpret what you are saying properly, perhaps it already has the functionality that you want.  See:  https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/entities

Comment: As I understand it, Datanucleus is the layer by which we access the GAE actual database which is BigTable-like? If that's the case, what do you mean by not needed the Datanucleus layer?

Comment: I should have wrote "you are not _required_ to use Datanucleus or any of the other fine ORM layers".  Using an ORM wouldn't add much, I don't think, if you are just saving keys/values.  It would be interesting to find out if the low-level API does what you want, and how your project turns out.

Answer (score 1):

Datanucleus is a specific framework that runs on top of GAE. You can however access the database at a lower, less structured, more key/value-like level - the low-level API. That's the lowest level you can access directly. 
BTW, the low-level-"GAE datastore" internally runs on 6 global Google Megastore tables, which in turn are hosted on the Google Big Table database system.
Saving JSON as a String works fine. But you will need ways to retrieve your objects other than by ID. That is, you need a way to index your data to support any kind of useful query on it.

Comment: You are right. There is this low-level GAE api. However, I want to capitalize with the Datanucleus layer.